# Using OrderedRDD functions in spark

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I am having trouble understanding the datatype of collections on which functions like sortByKey can be called. I have a ListMap (I want a data structure that stores elements in order) that I want to call sortByKey on. The content of the list map are the first n number as keys and 1 as value for each. What should I use instead of a list map?

```
val l = (1 to 1000).toList
val d = ListMap(l.map(s=> s -> 1):_*)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(d))
rdd.collect()
val sorted = rdd.sortByKey()
sorted.collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

The requirements are quite simple:

- You need a `RDD[(K, V)]`.
- There has to be an `implicit` `Ordering` for `K` present in the given scope.

Your example doesn't really make sense because `RDD` you create has only a single element so there is really nothing to sort. Perhaps you wanted something like this:

```
sc.range(1,  1001).map((_, 1)).sortByKey()
```

Comment: I tried that and it works. thanks! which part of my code snippet is making it only one element? I want to make sure the keys are already sorted so that the sorting algo is O(n) does doing a map like that result in rdd that is stored in order.

Comment: `Seq(d)`. You could replace it by `d.toSeq` but it is make that much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `ListMap`. All you need is an `RDD` which has an underlying tuple of key and value, in the form of `RDD[(K, V)]` where in your case we have an `RDD[(Int, Int)]`:

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize((1 to 1000).map(k => (k -> 1)).toSeq)

rdd.sortByKey().collect()
```

You also need an `Ordering`, which you currently get for free, implicitly, for primitive of type `Int`.

Comment: that worked! I am using a ListMap cause I want to make sure the keys are sorted so my input to the sorting function is already sorted. How can I make sure  that this rdd is ordered when it is passed to the sorting function.

Comment: @user Why would you want to sort something that's sorted? Not sure I follow.

Comment: I want shuffle reads and shuffle writes cause I want data to move across the network. But I want to not spend time doing an actual sort (actually, I dont even care if my end data is not sorted). From what I understand, spark uses tim sort which gives O(n) runtime for sorted data, so I want to make sure my data I am trying to sort is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spark programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html):

> **sortByKey**([ascending], [numTasks])
>
> When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs where K implements Ordered,
>   returns a dataset of (K, V) pairs sorted by keys in ascending or
>   descending order, as specified in the boolean ascending argument.

So you need a `PairRDD` where the key can be ordered, see the other answers for examples.